# Is it possible to run in offline mode with mods enabled?

Tags: steam, cities-skylines

Steam was down earlier today. When that's the case we can still launch steam in offline mode and play some games. Upon starting Cities and loading a save game, I noticed that the mods that I have installed from the Steam Workshop did not work because I was offline. Is there any way to by-pass this? You'd expect that mods are saved locally, so it seems odd that you need an internet connection for this.

Comment: I'm reading forums that are suggesting to make sure that the mods are located in local folders. Have you done that? It also looks like this is a bug that should've been fixed a while ago, though some people are still reporting it (like yourself)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The only problem you're likely to encounter is that the cloud saves and/or sync will be offline. Everything else should be stored locally.